# Palindrome arrangement problem

Tags: combinatorics, palindrome

How many five-letter palindromes are there (using ordinary 26 letter alphabet)?

I was thinking it was either using permutation with first three leters or using 26 cubed.

Thanks

Comment: That’s correct: the palindrome is completely determined by its first three letters, and any sequence of three letters is permissible.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you are looking for words of the form $ABCBA$, where $A,B,C$ can be one of the possible $26$ letters. Each of the $A,B,C$ has $26$ possibilities (since there is no restriction on $A,B,C$), so the total number is $26^3$.